# Tomcat 7.0 Certificate Update

Tags: tomcat

We have a windows server running Tomcat 7.0 which the SSL certificate has expired. We have a new certificate, but are unsure of how to update it to the new one. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

First, upgrade your Tomcat installation. 7.0 has been EOL for over 2 years now (and using certificates implies you have this exposed on the internet).

Have a look in server.xml to see how the certificate is currently deployed - either tomcat will be reading PEM files from the filesystem or retrieving the certificate and key from a designated Java certificate database. The latter is maintained using the [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) program with a file in PKCS#12 format. For the former, simply replace the files. For the latter, upload the certificate using the same name already in the config. (BTW the default password on Java certificate databases is `changeit`

e.g. here's the config from a nearby Linux box....

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="mywebsslcert"
               keystoreFile="/usr/local/etc/tomcat.jks"
               keystorePass="changeit" />
```

Comment: would this be the same for windows server as well?

Comment: `changeit` is the initial (not really default) password _for the system truststore `cacerts`_ but you should not put your own cert (here the server cert) in `cacerts` -- and your example doesn't. For a keystore you create the password is whatever you choose. `keytool` supports PKCS12, JKS, _and_ JCEKS in all versions, plus non-file-based stores, but in java 8 which you linked (and lower) it _defaults_ to JKS.